# Edit dual boot menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, windows

I have currently installed Ubuntu 14 and windows 10 alongside. For some reason, in the boot loader it shows of course Ubuntu, ando 2 entrys that say Windows 7. Both of them take me correctly to my windows 10, but it really bugs me and I want to change it to Windows 10 and remove one of them.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the graphical tool `grub-customizer`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

This tool lets you add/remove/rename boot entries, change boot order etc.

Once you are done do not forget to save your modification: <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Save</kbd>

[image: grub-customizer screenshot1]]

**Be careful when using this tool to not mess up GRUB.**

Comment: Can I also control the timer (which is 10 seconds by default) to 1 second?